# primefaces datatable row delete does not delete the same row in UI

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 4.0. I have a dynamic datatable with selectonemenu components on each row, along with delete button for each row. On click of delete button, the exact row gets deleted in the managedbean's List, but in the UI , i see only the last row getting deleted. This is very much misleading.

By googling a little i saw the same issue already addressed in the below link which say's immediate=true set in the delete button causes this problem.
[Primefaces 3.4 Datatable doesn't refresh correctly after delete row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558521/primefaces-3-4-datatable-doesnt-refresh-correctly-after-delete-row)

Wondering how can the immediate attribute cause this problem.

But my actual problem is that i cannot remove the immediate=true attribute , coz if i do, the delete button click will cause the validation phase to fire, and then i will get validation messages. I want the user to be able to delete teh rows inspite of the failed validation's and hence i did set immediate=true in my delete button so that the row is not validated.

Can anyone please help ?

```
                            <p:dataTable id="levDataTbl" value="#{leventrybean.leaves}" var="lev"
                             widgetVar="levDataTbl">  
                             <p:column >
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{lev.employee}"  var="e"
                                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" id="empDrpDown"
                                    rendered="#{leventrybean.sizeOfDirectorates > 0 }" required="true"
                                    styleClass="px75DrpDown" converter="empconverter" 
                                     >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-" itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{leventrybean.employees}" var="employee"
                                    itemLabel="#{employee.empName}" itemValue="#{employee}"/>   
                                    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" listener="#{lev.changeEmpListener}" /> 
                                    <p:column >
                                    #{e.empName}
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column >
                                    #{e.empCd}
                                    </p:column>         
                                </p:selectOneMenu>                                            
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{sessionScope['fullname']}" 
                                    rendered="#{leventrybean.sizeOfDirectorates == 0 }"
                                    />
                             </p:column>
                             <p:column >
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{lev.selectedLeaveType}" 
                                    filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" var="levtp" id="levDrpDown"
                                    rendered="true" converter="levtypconverter" styleClass="px75DrpDown"
                                    required="true">  
                                     <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select-" itemValue="" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{lev.leavesAllowed}" var="l"
                                        itemLabel="#{l.leaveTypeDesc}" itemValue="#{l}"/>
                                    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@form" listener="#{lev.changeLevTypListener}"/>    
                                    <p:column>#{levtp.leaveTypeDesc}</p:column>
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                             </p:column>
                             <p:column  style="width:6%">
                                <p:commandButton id="deleteLeave" update="@form" image="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"  >
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lev}" target="#{leventrybean.selectedLeaveForDel}" />
                                </p:commandButton>
                             </p:column>                                           
                            </p:dataTable>
```

Bean Code for the delete button is below...

```
public void setSelectedLeaveForDel(Leave obj){
    deleteLeave(obj);
}
private void deleteLeave(Object obj){
    try{

        this.leaves.remove(obj);

    }catch(Exception e){
        log.error("Error in deleteLeave() ::"+e);
        log.error(Utility.getStackTrace(e));            
    }    
}
```

Comment: No code. No code. No code. Why?

Comment: Apologies. Will update with the code soon.